# Can anyone tell me the best books for studying UAV?

Tags: arduino-uno

It's kind of hard to get full guide from the internet. I just wanna buy a book for UAV guide. I gotta make DIY drones. I'd appreciat it if you recommend good books.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE! I'm going to close this question because this isn't based on fact, more on opinion. Feel free to edit the question if you can make this more specific. Thanks!

Comment: oh. I'm sorry. I made a mistake.
I'm gonna upload more useful information next time.
Thanks ;)

Comment: that's fine, everyone gets a question or two closed once in a while. On a side note: [Related meta discussion](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/q/1220/220)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a book, but try the following course from EdX, the online MOOC:
https://www.edx.org/course/tumx/tumx-autonavx-autonomous-navigation-1658

Comment: wow. that's the great website.
I appreciate for your help. 
have a good day.